If I want to allocate a separate thread pool for a specific operation, how should I determine the thread pool size?
I have a Spring boot application running in production. I am implementing an async feature that exports a certain metric that can run on its separate thread pool without blocking the main application thread. I'm just thinking how to decide how many threads would I need for this?
I'm using Java and using the ExecuterService for that.
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);


Are your background tasks CPU-bound? Or do they involve blocking such as file I/O, logging, network calls, accessing a database, etc.?

@BasilBourque the latter

Test different values and find out.

Virtual Threads
You commented that your background tasks are not CPU-bound, that they do involve blocking such as file I/O, logging, network calls, accessing a database, etc.
In that case you should consider using virtual threads (fibers) in Java 21+. When using this executor service implementation, a new virtual thread is created for each task you submit. The thread ends when your task ends. Virtual threads are so “cheap” in terms of memory and CPU that you may be able to reasonably have millions of then running simultaneously on conventional hardware.
So, when using virtual threads, your Question here becomes moot. Never pool virtual threads.
Search Stack Overflow to learn more, as virtual threads has been addressed many times. See also excellent video talks by Ron Pressler, Alan Bateman, and José Paumard.
